# Определить объект window, которому принадлежит DOM-Element

Tags: javascript, dom, навигация

Имеется элемент `elem`. Нужно получить окно. С помощью `parentNode` можно добраться только до `document`. Как получить окно?

Comment: Просто window не подходит? У вас iframe, что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Окно может существовать только в одном экземпляре.
Для получения окна используй просто:

```
window
```

или можно без window:

```
window.location === location
```

Если ты работаешь во фрейме, то window будет указывать на окно текущего фрейма.

Comment: Вот именно, из фрейма. Нужно получить его window, а лучше сразу DOM-элемент <iframe> или <frame> для frameset родительского окна, в котором находится это окно. Т. е. обратное свойству contentWindow. Пока делаю так: нахожу родительское окно и перебираю фреймы, сравнивая их document с полченным через parentNode.

Comment: С iframe прокатывает, а с frameset проблема - они оказываются неравны

Comment: в вашем случае это единственный вариант. Возможно его усовершенствовать путем добавления _id_ фрейма у родителя и _get_ параметром передавать его фрейму.

Comment: Но я бы посоветовал вам пересмотреть архитектуру, и пользоваться **Web Messaging API** для общения между фреймами: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Messaging), [mdndoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)